# WooCommerce & CiviCRM Integration

Tags: custom-fields, integration, woocommerce

Can WooCommerce products be synced into CiviCRM Custom Fields?

I tried creating checkboxes in CiviCRM under a custom field & they are not getting checked off when someone purchases something in WooCommerce....

Any feedback?

Answer (score 2):

They guys at VedaConsulting developed a great extension that integrates Woocommerce with CiviCRM, no sure if is what you are looking for.

You can find it in their [github repository](https://github.com/veda-consulting/woocommerce_civicrm/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: We already have that plugin installed. It is not working with Custom Fields as far as I can understand.

Comment: Con you explain a bit more what is exactly do you want to achieve? Do the products in Woocommerce have custom fields that you want to sync with Civi?

Comment: We have a standard install of WooCommerce and CiviRM.Is it possible to set different contribution types depending on the product in WooCommerce? We originally thought it might be possible to fill custom fields inside CiviCRM from the info we got from WooCommerce, but that is unfortunately not possible with the plugin as of now but we might be able to work around that if we can set different types of contributions. And we discovered that $0.00 purchases are not getting imported into CiviCRM

Comment: If you are referring to different Financial types, yes it is possible, but you will need to extend the plugin. In my case we use two different Financial types, one for TAX (UK customers) and another one without TAX for non UK customers, so if a UK customer purchases an item/service in our shop the contribution logged in CiviCRM has tax automatically.

Comment: Didn't see your updated comment, what you describe is definitely possible but as I said you will need to extend the plugin per your requirements (either doing it yourself if you have the resources or hiring one of the CiviCRM partners, I guess VedaConsulting is the most appropriate in this case), perhaps if you update the question with a more specific description, we will be able to point you in the right direction.